# Error Message "The URL scheme 'OPCDA' is not supported" in Win10, Works Fine 2012 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, opc-da

We've got a system that has been making OPCDA calls without issue for some time - when calling Windows Server 2012 R2 (Version 6.3, Build 9600).  Recently, however, we've tried talking to a Windows 10 machine (Version 21H2 (OS Build 19044.1889 and we're getting an error:

> System.NotSupportedException: The URL scheme 'OPCDA' is not supported.

There must be something different between the two implementations; however, I've been unable to find any documentation. Anyone have suggestion on troubleshooting this?

Comment: Not much to go by, but by the error message suggests this machine is missing the protocol handler for "opcda".  Have a look-see at the registry of the good machine to have a cue what you need to install on the win10 machine: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-3x-wds-ph-install-registration#installing-and-registering-a-protocol-handler

Answer (score 0):

The .Net OPC API is case sensitive for its analysis of the URL scheme.  Convert it to lower case, and it will work (or at least get you to the next error).